# 'a narrow vocabulary' versus 'a restricted vocabulary': do both collocations exist? which is commoner?

Tags: adjectives, register

Do both collocations 'a narrow vocabulary' and 'a restricted vocabulary' exist?

And if they do, which is commoner/more common?

Answer (score 3):

A "restricted" vocabulary is one with fewer words than is considered normal. A "narrow" vocabulary is also a restricted vocabulary, but the restriction applies to the subjects described by that vocabulary, rather than the number of words available.

An example might be a comparison between a bright college student and an old, self-taught machinist. The college student might well have a larger vocabulary, while the machinist's might be narrow, with many words unique to the machinists trade which the college student lacks.

Comment: It's a fine distinction that won't be understood by everyone - many of whom will never have encountered *narrow vocabulary*, so they might just think it's "unidiomatic". But I think you're quite right. Example usage: [*the narrow vocabulary of physics*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22narrow+vocabulary+of+physics%22)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard people using *"a restricted vocabulary"*, but I've never come across *"a narrow vocabulary"*. It doesn't sound like it is incorrect though. I don't think it is used as commonly as *"a restricted vocabulary"*. 
However, there are a couple of things that I have heard being used more extensively that either of the two you have suggested, which are:

> - A **limited** vocabulary.
> - A **controlled** vocabulary.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+narrow+vocabulary%2Ca+restricted+vocabulary%2Ca+limited+vocabulary%2C+a+controlled+vocabulary&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20narrow%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20restricted%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20limited%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20controlled%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0) shows that *"a limited vocabulary"* and *"a controlled vocabulary"* are more commonly used.

**NOTE**: Please note that the usage of each terms may depend on your context. So my suggestions may not be valid. Since the context is unavailable, I've given you a couple more possible variations for your suggestions, which are also correct and are used, no matter how uncommonly they may be heard.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think either of them are very common, but neither of them sound bad. According to [google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+narrow+vocabulary%2Ca+restricted+vocabulary&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20narrow%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20restricted%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0), "A restricted vocabulary" is much more common.

Comment: I'd hardly say that a *restricted vocabulary* isn't very common (although it *is* true that [***a limited vocabulary***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+narrow+vocabulary%2Ca+restricted+vocabulary%2Ca+limited+vocabulary&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20narrow%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20restricted%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20limited%20vocabulary%3B%2Cc0) is far *more* common).